# why use wsgiref simple_server?

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, wsgi, wsgiref

I have a simple webapp to build, and I am just beginning to mess around with mod_wsgi. In various tutorials, the first hello world app looks something like the following:

```
def application(environ,start_response):
   response_body = 'Hello World'
   status = '200 OK'

   response_headers = [('Content-Type', 'text/plain'),
                       ('Content-Length', str(len(response_body)))]

   start_response(status, response_headers)
   return [response_body]
```

Then, later the app includes a wsgi server using wsgiref, some variation of:

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server

def application(environ, start_response):
    response_body = 'Hello World'
    status = '200 OK'

    response_headers = [('Content-Type', 'text/plain'),
                           ('Content-Length', str(len(response_body)))]

    start_response(status, response_headers)
    return [response_body]

httpd = make_server('localhost', 8000, application)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

The app works without the server, so what is the server for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would guess the tutorial assumes you do not have mod_wsgi set up and running. This way you can run the script from the command line and it will start the `wsgiref` server running the application so that you can test it without having to install Apache and mod_wsgi.

Comment: any reasons to use it still once you have mod_wsgi running... maybe benefits while testing?

Comment: Well, it might be easier to run it in `pdb` when running it from the command line with `wsgiref`, but apart from that I don't think so. If you put the `wsgiref` startup code in an `if __name__ == "__main__":` block, you should be able to easily switch between the two if you need to for whatever reason.

Comment: Should we use wsgiref.simple_server in production as well, i.e. without any Apache or Nginx?

Comment: @giga No, you should not use `wsgiref.simple_server` in production. It is meant to be a simple reference implementation/example. It may have security and/or performance issues. Use a proper web server like Apache or nginx.